# Qt state machine

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm reading the doc and trying to understand qt statemachine framework.

My approach is to inherit from QState and override the onEntry function then I do the logic of the state machine inside on Entry. I'm confused now on how to put a conditional transition. My logic inside onEntry was rewritten from a normal switch case machine and that logic has the transition.  How would I set the transition in the function OnEntry. Can someone show sample code ?

```
class s : public QState
{
public:
    s(QState *parent = 0);
    ~s();
protected:
    void onEntry(QEvent *event) override;
    void onExit(QEvent *event) override;

};

s::s(QState *parent): QState(parent)
{

}

s::~s()
{

}

void s::onEntry(QEvent *event)
{
    qDebug("on enter");
}

void s::onExit(QEvent *event)
{

}

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
   QStateMachine * m_machine = new QStateMachine();

    QState *rootState = new QState(m_machine);
    m_machine->setInitialState(rootState);
    s *state = new s(m_machine);

    m_machine->start();
 }

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `addTransition` to add transitions from this `State`. If you want to trigger transitions from the `onEntry` code, you should probably

a) define a new `SIGNAL` from this object;

b) `addTransition` from this state triggered on the `SIGNAL` defined in a);

c) emit this `SIGNAL` from your `onEntry` code.

Note that you shoud use queued connection when adding transition.

Comment: what is queued connection ? and does onEntry stays in the loop until the state in exit ?

Comment: Yeah, at first glance `addTransition` does not care about connection types. `onEntry` is run once every time the state becomes active.

Comment: Not tonight, sorry. Last time I dealt with QStateMachine was three years ago.

Comment: ok, I wait for you after the weekend, I'm interested to see the code please :)

Comment: should I connect to the signal from onEntry and use a slot

Comment: Oh, here's a question. Can you please post a minimal complete example of what is "normal switch case machine" and how you rewrote its logic inside `onEntry`?

Comment: I have provided a sample code of how to override the QState, but I dont know how to use that class and how to fire a signal from onEntry